# ES6 Subclass Array without Class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Out of interest, is it possible to subclass `Array` via the old prototype method? Would something like the following in theory work if any engines supported it?

```
function SubArray() {
    super();
}
SubArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
SubArary.prototype.constructor = SubArray;
SubArray.prototype.forEachRight ...
```

Comment: No engines support subclassing arrays, so no.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Not only because `super()` is not exactly the "old prototype method", but because it is not allowed outside of constructors:

> [§14.1.2 Static Semantics: Early Errors for function declarations and expressions](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors)
>
> It is a Syntax Error if *FunctionBody* `Contains` *SuperCall* is `true`.

You need to call `Array` as a constructor, so `Array.call(this, …)` does not work (in the same way as it didn't in ES5). However, thanks to the `Reflect` object it should be possible to fake the `super()` constructor call. We would use [`Reflect.construct`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-reflect.construct):

```
function SubArray() {
    return Reflect.construct(Array, [], SubArray)
}
…
```

---

Notice that you'd need to do something like

```
function SubArray() {
    …
}
Reflect.setPrototypeOf(SubArray, Array);
Reflect.setPrototypeOf(SubArray.prototype, Array.prototype);
```

to match the new `class` semantics, instead of doing `SubArray.prototype = Object.create(Array);`.

Comment: Is the SubArray not treated as a function when called with `new`?

Comment: @user2195592: Not sure what you mean? `SubArray` is a function. `new` makes a construct call.